# Tokenize Sentences or Tweets with Emoji Skin Tone Modifiers

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, spacy, emoji-tones

I want to tokenize a tweet containing multiple emojis and they are not space-separated. I tried both `NLTK TweetTokenizer` and `Spacy` but they fail to tokenize Emoji Skin Tone Modifiers. This needs to be applied to a huge dataset so performance might be an issue. Any suggestions?

**You may need to use Firefox or Safari to see the exact color tone emoji because Chrome sometimes fails to render it!**

```
# NLTK
from nltk.tokenize.casual import TweetTokenizer
sentence = "I'm the most famous emoji  but what about  and "
t = TweetTokenizer()
print(t.tokenize(sentence))

# Output
["I'm", 'the', 'most', 'famous', 'emoji', '', '', '', 'but', 'what', 'about', '', 'and', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

And

```
# Spacy
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
sentence = nlp("I'm the most famous emoji  but what about  and ")
print([token.text for token in sentence])

Output
['I', "'m", 'the', 'most', 'famous', 'emoji', '', '', '', 'but', 'what', 'about', '', 'and', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Expected Output

```
["I'm", 'the', 'most', 'famous', 'emoji', '', '', '', 'but', 'what', 'about', '', 'and', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: What color shading has to do with the emoji unicode?

Answer (score 4):

You should try using [spacymoji](https://github.com/ines/spacymoji). It's an extension and pipeline component for spaCy that can optionally merge combining emoji like skin tone modifiers into single token.

Based on the README you can do something like this:

```
import spacy
from spacymoji import Emoji

nlp = spacy.load('en')
emoji = Emoji(nlp, merge_spans=True) # this is actually the default
nlp.add_pipe(emoji, first=True)

doc = nlp(...)
```

That should do it.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks. Do you think a regex can do the same job?

Comment: Maybe, but I wouldn't recommend it, it'd just be harder to work with.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The reason I asked for is Spacy tokenize `I'm` as `I` and `'m` which is not the desired token I want.

Comment: Unless there's a whole lot of cases like that I would recommend just using some post-processing to fix the spaCy tokens. For cases like `I'm` it should be very simple. Alternately you could use spaCy to replace emoji with filler tokens like `EMOJI_HAND` and then use another tokenizer you prefer; it'd be slow but give you a lot of control.

Answer (score 1):

Skin tone modifiers are just a set of hex codes utilized in conjunction with the emoji's base hex code.
These are the skin tone modifiers :
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Diversity

[image]

You can use spacy retokenizer's [merge method](https://spacy.io/api/doc#retokenizer.merge) after finding the bounds of a token which is an emoji + its skin tone modifier.

See this answer of mine for how to merge tokens based on regex pattern : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43390171/533399